# java synchronization block multiple condition check

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, synchronized

I have the following code

```
public class MyClass {

    private boolean condition1;
    private boolean condition2; 
    private boolean condition3;

    public void start(){

        synchronized (this) {
            while(true){
                if(!condition1 || !condition2 || !condition3) break;
                .....//line #1
                if(!condition1 || !condition2 || !condition3) break;
                .....//line #2
                if(!condition1 || !condition2 || !condition3) break;
                .....//line #n
            }
        }

    }

}
```

condition1 to 3 can be mutated by other objects. What I want to achieve is to break out of the looping immediately when any other object has set any of the condition to false. Surely there's a better way than putting one-liner if check before each line's execution?

Thanks

Comment: And what happens when: You check that the "if condition" is false, and before you execute line#1, some other thread made the condition unfavourable (i.e. made condition1, or condition2, or condition3 as false) for you to execute line#1?

Comment: Wait!  You're putting a _loop_ inside a synchronized block?  Even without the loop, that seems like it could be a lot of code.  The purpose of a `synchronized` block is to perform some set of statements as an atom.  If it makes sense to break out of the synchronized block at point A or point B or point C, then you're doing things in there that do not need to be atomic.  Your `synchronized` blocks should always be as small as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Well actually in genereal there is not. From common sence it is not unreasonable make such checks only in long running blocks inside your loop, i.e. not after each command.

As minumum I suggest you fix some compile-time errros, say `!condition1` will not compile, as it is not `boolean` type. It should be `!condition.get()`.

Next it inevitably comes to mind create check method: `boolean test() { return !condition1.get() || ... ; }` and use it in `if (test()) break;` instead of copying long `if(!condition1.get() || ...)` line multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

```
while(!condition1 || !condition2 || !condition3) {

}
```

should do it, no?

better to combine the condition check into a separate method tho, as @Andremonly suggested.

If your conditions can be updated by other threads, they should be marked volatile when you declare them.

Comment: with that, the check will be once per loop, not once per line of code.